# Show that the hyperbolic sine function is bijective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

I am supposed to show that sinh : R -> R is bijective and I'm a bit lost. I suppose the part of showing that it's injective isn't so bad but I'm having some problems with showing that it's surjective. I know the definition of a function being surjective of course but I really don't understand how to apply it here, grateful for any help I can get here.

Comment: Hint: intermediate value theorem

Comment: IVT is a great solution. Another way: the equation $y=\frac12(e^x+e^{-x})$ is a quadratic equation in $e^x$ in disguise, and so it can be solved for $e^x$ and thus $x$.

Comment: Solve
$$
y=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}
$$
for $x$.

Comment: @yoyo ,Greg Martin, GEdgar So I solved it for x and got x= ln(y+sqrt(y^2+1)) which seems correct according to the definition but isn't this the inverse of sinh too? The reason I ask is beacuse I was supposed to show sinh being bijective so that I could  evalute the inverse but now it seems like I did that in the same step as showing it being surjective? Is my reasoning wrong here?